# CSS Transitions works only after waiting

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions

I'm building a responsive Angular web-site ([can be viewed here](http://jacksoncmorgan.com/newSite/#/)) and have built a directive to handle my site's header. But, there's some weird behaviour with the CSS transitions.

I'll first go over what is supposed to happen:

- When the window is resized below 600px, "home" and "projects" slides out of the way.
- When you click on the green square, the orange panel slides down and the blue boxes rearrange in a more condensed form.
- When you click the green square again, the orange panel slides back up and the blue boxes return to their previous position.

By the end of everything, all the elements are in their desired location, but sometimes the animation works and other times it doesn't.

- Clicking to expand the orange panel never displays an animation
- The animation for moving the blue boxes when the orange panel expands is never displayed.
- Condensing the orange panel will only display animation if the user waits before condensing it. Expanding the panel, then quickly clicking on the green square will cause the animation to fail.
- The successful display of animations when resizing seems to be sporadic.

This might have something to do with the way updates to the scope are applied in Angular directives, but I think it is probably something about CSS transitions as they are still somewhat experimental. Following is my CSS for this header:

```
#headerDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: orange;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
}
.headerUnexpanded {
    height: 50px;
}
.headerExpanded {
    height: 150px;
}
#headerCenter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    overflow: visible;
}

#headerIcon {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
}

#headerHome {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
}
#headerHome.here {
    top: 5px;
    right: 175px;
}
#headerHome.gone {
    top: 5px;
    right: 300px;
}
#headerHome.expand {
    top: 55px;
    right: 50px;
}

#headerProjects {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
}
#headerProjects.here {
    top: 5px;
    left: 175px;
}
#headerProjects.gone {
    top: 5px;
    left: 300px;
}
#headerProjects.expand {
    top: 55px;
    left: 50px;
}

#headerResume {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#headerContact {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your javascript code? Nothing in the CSS transitions looks out of order.

Comment: A link to the page or jsFiddle wouldn't hurt either so we can use some browser dev tools to inspect the code

Answer (score 0):

for your first problem can you set the min-width of the navigator to 700 px or what you want.

what i should do for the problem where all the buttons move when you click on the green button is to make a divm below the header bar. so when you click on the green button that bar slide down.

I hope this wiill help you a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's currently a glitch in Angular that causes difficulties with CSS3 animations. I'm not clear on the nuances, but I updated it to use a declarative animation library instead.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I am experiencing a similar problem and am trying to research it.